# NoMethodError in Discussions#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

Can anyone help me to fix this?Thanks in advance!
I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Discussions#new
Showing C:/Users/punitha/aggregator/app/views/discussions/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `discussions_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x4375758>:0x437d6d8>

Extracted source (around line #1):

1  <%= form_for @discussions do |f| %>
2  <% if @discussions.errors.any? %>
3        <div id="error_explanation">
4        <h2><%= pluralize(@discussions.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
```

Trace of template inclusion: `app/views/discussions/new.html.erb`

Rails.root: `C:/Users/punitha/aggregator`

```
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/discussions/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_discussions__form_html_erb___1058370717_35436840'
app/views/discussions/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_discussions_new_html_erb__298093787_35389404'
```

And the file _form.html.erb is

```
<%= form_for @discussions do |f| %>
<% if @discussions.errors.any? %>
 <div id="error_explanation">
 <h2><%= pluralize(@discussions.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
     this discussion from being saved:</h2>
 <ul>
    <% @discussions.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
 <% end %>
 <p>
<%= f.label :source_url %><br>
<%= f.text_field :source_url %>
  </p>

 <p>
<%= f.label :discussion_id %><br>
<%= f.text_area :discussion_id %>
 </p>

<p>
<%= f.label :discussion_msg %><br>
<%= f.text_area :discussion_msg %>
</p>

 <p>
 <%= f.label :discussion_type %><br>
 <%= f.text_field :discussion_type %>
 </p>

<p>
<%= f.label :discussion_link %><br>
<%= f.text_area :discussion_link %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.label :discussion_thumb %><br>
<%= f.text_area :discussion_thumb %>
 </p>
<p>
<%= f.label :discussion_permalink %><br>
<%= f.text_area :discussion_permalink %>
</p>

<p>
<%= f.label :discussion_likecount %><br>
<%= f.number_field :discussion_likecount%>
 </p>

<p>
<%= f.label :comment %><br>
<%= f.text_area :comment%>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.label :source_id %><br>
<%= f.number_field :source_id%>
</p>

 <p>
<%= f.submit %>
 </p>
 <% end %>
```

And my app/views/discussions/new.html.erb is,

```
<h1>New discussion</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', discussions_path %>
```

routes.rb file

```
Aggregator::Application.routes.draw do
get "welcome/index"
root 'welcome#index'


resources:discussions do
resources :comments
end
end
```

Comment: Apparently you're calling a route which is not defined. Can you share your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: Put a space between resources and: discussions.

Comment: @punitha can you post controller's action where you are defining `@discussions`?

Answer (score 0):

You're `form_for` is set to an array (`@discussions`) when it should be to a single instance (`@discussion`).

In your DiscussionsController's new method, ensure you have something along the following:

```
@discussion = Discussion.new
```

Then, in your form, change your current form_for expression to:

```
form_for @discussion
```

See if that clears your error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should correct your typo mistake in `routes.rb`.

It should looks like (I have added a space between `resources` and `:discussions`):

```
Aggregator::Application.routes.draw do
  get "welcome/index"
  root 'welcome#index'

  resources :discussions do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

As Craig Kaminsky said, it seems you are having `@discussions` as an array of `discussion` records.'

In your controller's action `new`, you should initialize your object as:

```
@discussion = Discussion.new
```

And you form should use same instance variable (`@discussion`)

```
  <%= form_for @discussion do |f| %>
    <% if @discussion.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@discussion.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        ...
    <% end %>
    ...
    ...
  <% end %>
```